# Varnish: what's the difference between Execstart malloc and DAEMON_OPTS malloc?

Tags: varnish

I'm using Varnish 4.x. I've read around a little but I can't understand what's the difference between the 2.

Are they the same thing?

Lets take a concrete example. I have a 16GB server. Of those 16GB I want to allocated to Varnish 4GB to cache whatever it's caching.

Where can I set that?

Currently I have the following configs:

```
ExecStart= ... malloc,4000m

DAEMON_OPTS=" ... malloc,512m"
```

Will the actual caching be done with the ExecStart config or the DAEMON_OPTS config?

---

I'm assuming it will be done with the ExecStart since the daemon one is just the process itself(I assume).

Can anybody clarify that please?

Comment: Usually the command line overrides the environment variables, but I can't find anything definitive in the Varnish docs. It should be trivial to test this though.